# How to apply a delta to a string in ace.js

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

Lets say I want to apply a delta to a single string, for example:

```
My multiline
string
```

And I want to apply a [delta](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=api&api=edit_session) to that string, for example:

```
{"start":{"row":3,"column":78},"end":{"row":3,"column":79},"action":"insert","lines":["e"],"id":3}
```

Now, I dont want this exactly, but is there any [ace.js](https://ace.c9.io/) function to process a delta on a **Stadalone** string?

EDIT: For your information, deltas are `ace.js`'s way of knowing what edit happened

Also, by applying a delta, I specifically mean the `redo` function in `ace.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to create an instance of ace document, call its applyDelta method  and then call getValue. You could also reimplement the logic, but it wouldn't be much faster as you'd still need to split the string into lines to find the position of insertion.

```
Document = ace.require("ace/document").Document
doc = new Document("My \n multiline\n sting")
doc.applyDelta({
    start:{"row":2,"column":3},
    end:{"row":2,"column":4},
    action:"insert",
    lines:["r"],
})
doc.getValue()
```